# How do I create  XML using XmlSerializer on Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, filewriter

I am creating an XML file using XmlSerializer. My code is given below.

```
Iterator<TypeClass> itr=dataarray.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
        try{
        TypeClass type=itr.next();
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "family");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "FamilyID");xmlserializer.text(type.getF_id());xmlserializer.endTag("", "FamilyID");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "FamilyHead");xmlserializer.text(type.getF_head());xmlserializer.endTag("", "FamilyHead");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "FamilyAddress");xmlserializer.text(type.getH_name());xmlserializer.endTag("", "FamilyAddress");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "Phone");xmlserializer.text(type.getPh_num());xmlserializer.endTag("", "Phone");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "Ward");xmlserializer.text(type.getW_num());xmlserializer.endTag("", "Ward");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "Latitude");xmlserializer.text(String.valueOf(type.getLat()));xmlserializer.endTag("", "Latitude");
        xmlserializer.startTag("", "Longitude");xmlserializer.text(String.valueOf(type.getLon()));xmlserializer.endTag("", "Longitude");
        xmlserializer.endTag("", "family");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("z", "inside while exception :"+e);
        }
    }
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "Families");
    FileWriter file=new FileWriter(familyxml);
    file.write(writer.toString());
    file.flush();
    file.close();
```

My problem is that at the end of the loop some data is not being added to the XML file. Here's what I get:

```
<family><FamilyID>~value~</FamilyID><FamilyHead>NINAN PHILIPOSE</FamilyHead><FamilyAddress>~value~</FamilyAddress><Phone>~value~</Phone><Ward>~value~</Ward><Latitude>0</Latitude><Longitude>0</Longitude></family><family><FamilyID>~value~</FamilyID><FamilyHead>MATHEW M C</FamilyHead><FamilyAddress>~value~
```

No other tags.?????

Comment: Where are you getting this result? Copy from logcat or xml file?

Comment: I think the error is with the String Writer (writer). If you want to create a large xml file don't use xmlserializer. Instead that just write it to file as string. Call the write method inside the loop.